# Get all substrings with brackets "<" and ">" in vba

Tags: vba

I am trying to get all values in columns D and E which include only these with brackets - like ;;;;VariableG5>
but without these with text NEW_LINE.I found only how to extract the text between the brackets, but I want to extract it with the brackets.This is what I found:

```
    Public Sub My_Split()

    Dim z As Variant

    z = Split(Replace(Join(Filter(Split(Replace(Replace(Selection.Value, "<" , ">")

    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, UBound(z) + 1) = z

     End Sub
```

Comment: A also tried with regex regular expressions and found a solution but the code doesn`t return the matches from the string pattern:

Comment: So you can extract the text but you just need to keep the brackets? Why not just use `Selection.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, UBound(z) + 1) = "<" & z & ">"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub simpleRegex()
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = " <([a-z] | [A-Z] | [0-9] | \. | - | _)+>"
Dim Match As Object
Dim matches As Object

Dim regex As Object
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim strInput As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("D8:D10")

For Each cell In Myrange
    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = cell.Value

        With regex
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regex.Test(strInput) Then
            Set matches = regex.Execute(strInput)
            For Each Match In matches
                MsgBox (Match.Value) 'A workaround I found to see if my pattern
                                     'worked but I need to print Match.value
                                     'in a column so this wont do
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox ("Not matched")
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```